# Firebase web modular API get() and dbRef

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, modular

I am migrating from the Firebase namespaced to modular API.
There is one detail I do not fully understand.

I have replaced the `once()` call with `get()`, but it's the database reference usage that confuses me. I have already initiated and exposed the database in a separate file using.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

export { database };
```

This reference is then used to create database refs.

```
import { database } from '../firebase/firebase'

const uidRef = ref(database, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`);
onValue(uidRef, (mySnapshots) => {
...
```

However, when using `get()` I have to use `getDatabase()` to avoid errors.

```
import { ref, getDatabase, get, child } from "firebase/database";

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(child(dbRef, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`)).then((mySnapshots) => {
```

In other words, the below code ***does not*** work

```
import { database } from '../firebase/firebase'

get(child(database, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`)).then((mySnapshots) => {
```

Why is that? They both seems valid to me.

I cannot see any explanation for the behaviour in the documentation -->

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get

EDIT:
The error I receive is:

> index.esm2017.js:2900  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pieceNum_')

Upon examination this error originates from

```
get(child(database, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`)).then((mySnapshots) => {
```

and then gets caught at

```
function child(parent, path) {
    parent = getModularInstance(parent);
    if (pathGetFront(parent._path) === null) { //<--- THIS LINE
        validateRootPathString('child', 'path', path, false);
    }
    else {
```

and then finally gets caught here

```
function pathGetFront(path) {
    if (path.pieceNum_ >= path.pieces_.length) { // <-- THIS LINE
        return null;
```

EDIT:

The syntax below works, still not sure what the benefit / damage of this usage is though compared to `ref(getDatabase());`.

```
get(child(ref(database), `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`)).then((mySnapshots) => {
```

Still not sure which way is the preferred / best practice.

Comment: "does not work" is hard to help with. Do you get any error message?

Comment: Hello Frank, and sorry for being so unspecific.  I have updated my question to include am explanation of the error. :) /K

Comment: `console.log(dbPathAccess , uid)` on the line above the `get(...)` call. One of these variables likely doesn't have a value.

Comment: Hello again! :) Both those variables contains a value ('access_groups' and 'Qbs3vaFtSECRETtWyCABC123'). However the exported database variable seems off, maybe because it is not a ref?  If I change it to ref(database) it seems to work. See updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the [`get` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#get_20b2416) needs to be a `Query` (or a [`DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.databasereference), which extends `Query`). A [`Database` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.database) is not a `Query` or `DatabaseReference`, so it can't be passed as the first argument to `get()`.

So the correct call is:

```
get(ref(database, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`))
```