# Firebase web modular API getDatabase()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a follow up question to my post here -->
[Firebase web modular API get() and dbRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974744/firebase-web-modular-api-get-and-dbref)

I am migrating from the Firebase namespaced to modular API. There is one detail I do not fully understand.

I have initiated and exposed the database in a separate file using:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

export { database };
```

But, a the file where `database` is imported from the above, I can write

```
import { database } from './firebase/firebase';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(ref(dbRef, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`)).then((mySnapshots) => {
```

instead of

```
import { database } from './firebase/firebase';

get(ref(database, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`))
```

My question is:

Are there any negative side-effects of using `getDatabase()` or is it good practice to use `getDatabase()` opposed to just `ref(database)`?

I cannot seem to find any extensive documentation on how `getDatabase()` works.

EDIT - due to mix up of db ref and db object

But, in a the file where `database` is imported from the above, I can write

```
import { database } from './firebase/firebase';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

get(ref(getDatabase(), `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`)).then((mySnapshots) => {
```

instead of

```
import { database } from './firebase/firebase';

get(ref(database, `${dbPathAccess}/${uid}`))
```

My question is:

Are there any negative side-effects of using `getDatabase()` or is it good practice to use `getDatabase()` opposed to just (in my case) `database`?

Comment: Does this line `const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());` really work? Because you should pass a `FirebaseApp` to the [`getDatabase()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md?authuser=0#getdatabase_d9cea01) method.

Comment: Should you really always do that? Both arguments are optional. Using just getDatabase() works just fine for me! :) For example: get(ref(getDatabase(), `${dbPath}/${uid}`)); I see now that I have still confused the db ref() and the db object, though :D

Comment: I guess that, since the above file that initiates the database is included in the entry point for my application getDatabase() then knows what default database to return.

Answer (score 2):

The [`getDatabase` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#getdatabase_d9cea01) returns a `Database` object., while the [`ref` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#ref_5f88fa2) returns a `DatabaseReference` object. These are different object, and you should get the object that you need.

Comment: The query is not about the difference between `getDatabase` and `ref` themselves, but over the impact of using `ref(getDatabase(), ...)` (imported directly from "firebase/database") vs. `ref(database, ...)` (imported via the init script in "./firebase/firebase"). e.g. is there a way that the return value of `getDatabase()` and the variable `database` would not be the same object?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you! \\(^__^)/  And also - are there possible linked side effects that might affect efficiency during run time when choosing one over the other! /K

Answer (score 1):

other then the mistake in the code as highlighted by the @RenaudTarnec in above comment ,here i am going to just focus on the subject.but also understand the fact that

> **ref(db, path) or ref(database, path)**
>
> Reference representing the location in the Database corresponding to
> the provided path. If no path is provided, the Reference will point to
> the root of the Database.

> **getDatabase(app, url)**
>
> Returns the instance of the Realtime Database
> SDK that is associated with the provided FirebaseApp. Initializes a
> new instance with with default settings if no instance exists or if
> the existing instance uses a custom database URL.

so if you just need to get the data then using `getDatabase()` will be the option but if you want to use the reference representing the location in the Database then just use the`ref(db,path)`

but as you asked from the point of stander or good practice to follow then you should understand that there is no negative effect of using `getDatabase()`. people consider it as better practice because it provide better readability and maintainability. Please try to go through the following explanation.

if you and your team-mates  are using the one type lets say `getDatabase()` or `ref(db, path)` then for the shake of consistency just stick with that one.

other view is that if you use `getDatabase()` in your project it provide better readability and understanding to other members because by just looking at the word `getDatabase` every one gets to know from here we are accessing the database on the other hand `ref(db, path)` may not be that obvious of the new Joiners to understand just by word.

also if you use `getDatabase()` and you wish to modify the initialization file according to your future needs then you have to just make changes on one place and just with that it will be reflected in all of your project ,on the other hand if you uses `ref(db, path)` then you gonna have to update every instance where database is imported and of-course it will consume more time.